# Copy a customized list form's power app from one site to another

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a SharePoint online custom list, which I have customized its list forms ( Create & Edit ) using Microsoft Power Apps.

Now I created another list on a new SharePoint Online site, which have the same fields and settings as the original list. So is there a way to Copy-Past or Import-Export the power app form, from one list to another list on different site?

I tried to find a way to Export/Import the list but I could not find any..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open source tool called "Flow & Power Apps Migrator"](https://github.com/Zerg00s/FlowPowerAppsMigrator). It converts exported Apps, Flows and Solutions to be compatible with the target tenant or site.

[image]

It also migrates lists that are used as a datasource by the Apps and Flows.

[image]